# C# move cursor on screen based on where text appears on desktop

Tags: c#, .net-core

So I have searched and can't seem to find the right resources or tools for what I am wanting to do so I thought I'd ask for some help. Below is what I am wanting to do.

I am making a .Net core application that will simulate some key strokes and that is all working fine, but I want to also move the mouse based on where certain text appears on the screen, however, I will not have control over the application where the text appears, so I will need to somehow either be streaming the desktop view and using something to analyze it, or constantly taking a screen shot every 10 seconds or so and analyzing that screen shot if the text is there and then move the mouse to that position of text and simulate a left click.

I am not really confident in the screenshot approach as I am not sure how I'd get the mouse coordinates, so I have a feeling I will need to feed a desktop stream into something in order to get the image I am analyzing and then overlay my own transparent overlay on top of that in order to move the cursor to appropriate position.

I hope this makes sense and any libraries or whatever that is recommended to do this is appreciated. I know how to move the cursor on the screen and left click, just haven't found on google the right library for analyzing a desktop screen in real time and getting coordinates based on searching conditions.

Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured out what I needed to do. Trying to match the text with and OCR proved to be impossible as the text was layered into an image where they actively tried to prevent detection, this is because its a video game and they don't want automation I guess. So what I did was determine I will always know what the button is going to look like, so I took a screen shot of the button and now I take screenshots of the game every 10 seconds and then search that image for my button template image. If the image has a match, then I generate coordinates and send mouse there and click it. Below is the code I used and you will need the libraries from AForge to use this code.

```
Bitmap sourceImage = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(@"C:\testjpg.jpg");
Bitmap template = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(@"C:\buttonjpg.jpg");
// create template matching algorithm's instance

//Resize value
var resizePercent = 0.4;

//Resizing images to increase process time. Please note this will result in skewed coordinates. 
//You must divide the coordinates by your resizePercent to get native coordinates taken from screen shots.
sourceImage = new ResizeBicubic((int)(sourceImage.Width * resizePercent), (int)(sourceImage.Height * resizePercent)).Apply(sourceImage);
template = new ResizeBicubic((int)(template.Width * resizePercent), (int)(template.Height * resizePercent)).Apply(template);

// (set similarity threshold to 0.951f = 95.1%)
ExhaustiveTemplateMatching tm = new ExhaustiveTemplateMatching(0.951f);
// find all matchings with specified above similarity

TemplateMatch[] matchings = tm.ProcessImage(sourceImage, template);
// highlight found matchings

BitmapData data = sourceImage.LockBits(
     new Rectangle(0, 0, sourceImage.Width, sourceImage.Height),
     ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, sourceImage.PixelFormat);
foreach (TemplateMatch m in matchings)
{

    Drawing.Rectangle(data, m.Rectangle, Color.White);

    Console.WriteLine(m.Rectangle.Location.ToString());

    var x = m.Rectangle.Location.X;
    var y = m.Rectangle.Location.Y;

    //Fixing the coordinates to reflex the origins of the original screenshot, not the resized one.
    var xResized = (int)(x / resizePercent);
    var yResized = (int)(y / resizePercent);

    // do something else with matching
}
sourceImage.UnlockBits(data);
```

I did notice my coordinates were off usually around ~4.5%-8% from dead center(the button still gets clicked, but I want a perfect center click), so for me I am calculating a range of coordinates, which in this range are not very many to ensure the button I want to click is clicked and not missed and just having program click all the potential coordinates.

So I hope this helps someone!

Kind Regards,

Aaron

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the application there are a number of approaches you might want to try.

For example, using [Application Insights](https://accessibilityinsights.io) and [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-overview), you might be able to capture the text directly.

If you have the exe file, then you might be able to decompile it with something like [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler) and then use Visual Studio's Live debugging feature to access the text.

You might be able to inspect the heap of the running process via a tool like [HeapMemView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/heap_memory_view.html).

Optical Character Recognition might be an option worth considering. In that case [Tesseract](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Tesseract) is an open source OCR engine worth considering. This can be used in conjunction with screenshots to extract text.

Comment: Thank you for comment. Out of these I also need to get the coordinates of the text so I can move cursor. Also I won't have access to exe so it needs to be a solution that is independent of the application.  I basically need something watching the desktop and not so much a specific program.

Comment: Also something that can take a screen shot and analyze for specific text and get coordinates is acceptable too. As I can take Screencast every 20 seconds and then delete.